# WordPress notification rest API code

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Like WordPress give us rest API for comments, posts etc.  I want to get notification API code.

developer.wordpress.com gives the documentation for how to use notification API.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/notifications/$note_ID/.

To use this API, I need WordPress rest API notification code.

How can I get that code.

WordPress rest API code doesn't have notification code.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get notification id using rest api.

**Note :** assume id is 1801481297

```
<?php
$options  = array (
  'http' => 
  array (
    'ignore_errors' => true,
    'header' => 
    array (
      0 => 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN',
    ),
  ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$response = file_get_contents(
    'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/notifications/1801481297',
    false,
    $context
);
$response = json_decode( $response );
?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me a bit more? I have already found this code in developer.wordpress.com doc tab. But if I run this code through postman, its give me "no route found" error.

Comment: see this: https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/notifications/seen/

<?php
$options  = array (
  'http' => 
  array (
    'ignore_errors' => true,
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 
    array (
      0 => 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN',
      1 => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ),
    'content' => 
     http_build_query(  array (
        'time' => '1420936513',
      )),
  ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$response = file_get_contents(
    '', false,  $context
);
$response = json_decode( $response );?>

Comment: In wp rest API, we have code file for posts, comments,  After that we can set endpoint and get data through APIs. I want to get code file for notification API.

Comment: then whats an issue which version are you using v2 ??

Comment: In wp rest API, we have code file for posts, comments,  After that we can set endpoint and get data through APIs. I want to get code file for notification API.
if I am testing notification api through postman. Like : 
http://localhost/projects/my_project/wp-json/sd2/v0.1/notifications/seen 
method : POST
Its give me an error  : {"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}

Because there is no code file where endpoint "notification" will communicate.

Comment: did you check other api??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131644/discussion-between-upcoming-developer-and-vasim-vanzara).